# Deleting an Even page header on OSX MAC Microsoft Office 2011

Tags: macos

I have a huge space on the second page of my resume. It seems there is a defined header on it, causing the appearance of my resume to look unprofessional. How do I delete the even page header to pul up my information to the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Create new document

[image: Create new document]

Add header by double clicking in header section.

[image: Add header by double clicking in header section]

Add random content.

[image: Add random content]

Insert section break at the end of the page.

[image: Insert section break at the end of the page.]

Un-check Link as Previous under the Header Footer context menu

[image: Un-check Link as Previous under the Header Footer context menu]

Select header text on the second page header.

[image: Select header text on the second page header.]

Delete the text.

Comment: I did everything that you told me to do but, on the final step how do you delete the header? Thank you

Comment: Updated my answer with images.